# query to Update another table if first update fails in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a .sql file with some update queries.

What i am looking for is when an update query fails, i should be able to execute another update query

e.g. `Update table1 set col1="zbc" where id=1;`
suppose above query fails as "id=1" was not found.

Then i want to execute below query to do update on another table:

```
Update table2 set col1="zbc" where id=1;
```

Since i want this to go in .sql file, I am looking for a single query to achieve this using if/case statement or something similar.

Comment: I'd load the data into a new table, then try the update to table1.  If it fails, update table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if just run the second query and check if these rows exist in the first table for example:

```
Update table1 set col1="zbc" where id=1;
Update table2 set col1="zbc" where id=1 
                             and not exists (select id from table1 where id=1);
```

or use [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) MySql function and IF. It returns the number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted by the last statement.

Comment: this is one option, but m avoiding it as this will mean running one extra update query for every update. effectievly if i have to do 500 updates, i need to run 1000 queries. not so good an option.

Comment: I've edited my answer: try to use the ROW_COUNT() mySql function

Comment: thnx valex for ur ans :)

example of using ROW_COUNT() with IF function:

Update table1 set col1="zbc" where id=1;
update table2 set col1="zbc" where id=1 and if(ROW_COUNT()=0,1,0)=1;

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a stored procedure and call that procedure from the .sql file contents? The MySQL manual states that if/then clauses are supported only in "stored programs":
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html